# Is the first layer safe to touch after printing with heated bed adhesive (PrimaFix)?

Tags: adhesion, safety, health

I just purchased the PrimaFix heated bed adhesive for my 3D printer. I read on the back of the box that it's dangerous when it comes in contact with the eyes, skin, mouth and when swallowed.

After printing, is it safe to touch the first layer? If not, what should I do to make it safe to touch?

[image]

Comment: I imagine that the warning is related to the state when it is fluid, not dried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general purpose catch all warning that some people with sensitive skin might have a rash like reaction, and you should never put these things in your mouth or eyes anyway.

It just means that you should treat it like you would super glue.

Once it's dry it's inert and safe to handle